# Unable to read file, outputting what looks like a different encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I'm writing a program that takes a bunch of user input and saves it all to a file, right now I'm testing the files to make sure everything works well. However, while reading the file I get the following output:

```
['\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
...
]
```

I'm creating the file using `uuid` for the filename, I'm not sure if that would have anything to do with it, and filling the file with user input:

```
import uuid

def create_rand_filename():
    return "{}.txt".format(uuid.uuid4())

def gather_intel():
    results = []
    number_of_empty_responses = 0
    while True:
        data = raw_input("Copy and paste the work log: ")
        if data == "":
            number_of_empty_responses += 1
            if number_of_empty_responses == 2:
                return "\n".join(results)
        else:
            number_of_empty_responses = 0
            results.append(data)
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(create_rand_filename(), "a+") as rand_file:
        rand_file.write(gather_intel())

        print rand_file.readlines()
```

What is causing the output to show up as what appears to be a different encoding, and how can I fix this so that I can read the file?

Comment: Don't you need a `seek` between the `write` and `readlines`?

Comment: @MarkRansom You're correct, why is that though?

Comment: Because files have a pointer, and when you `write` you leave the pointer at the end of the file. Reading from there won't return anything. Please edit your code to show the missing seek. P.S. I don't see any indication of any encoding, you just have a file full of null bytes that exists before you append to it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well actually I was missing the seek, you are completely correct about that, so if you post an answer I'll accept it. I'm new to python so thank you

Comment: In that case I don't understand your output at all. `readlines` should have given you an empty list.

Comment: Nope, gave me that, and if I did `read()` it showed a bunch of blank lines.